# Can I get my money back from a collections agency if I can prove that the initial company was negligent with notifications?

Tags: united-states, collections

I am not sure if this was a technical error, but I ported a Frontier phone number which was being used for Fios. That caused the account to be closed. A few days before, I had paid that account in full, so I thought all was good. I had them open a new account and restore my internet following this issue, and I paid the new balance in full every month, all unaware that there was still an outstanding balance on the first account.

On 2 August, I got a verbal notice from a collections agency, and they were the ones who told me about where they got their information.

Is this likely to appear on my credit report, and can I dispute this even after agreeing to pay the amount I owed, plus an additional fee to the collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this likely to appear on my credit report, and can I dispute this
>   even after agreeing to pay the amount I owed, plus an additional fee
>   to the collector?

It won't appear in your credit report because you readily made (or that's what I gather from your inquiry) the payment they requested. You might get within the next few days a letter from the collections agency reflecting your payment, including also an unwarranted/moot statement about what would occur to your credit score if you default (I consider it *unwarranted* because agency itself has acknowledged the payment).

As for the second part of your question, my conjecture is that you are entitled to a reimbursement if you are able to prove that you were up-to-date in your payments.

I think I experienced something similar to what you describe: In 2012, I canceled AT&T, made the *early termination* fee AT&T determined, and then an additional "adjustment" fee from overseas. On both occasions, AT&T assured me that I was up-to-date. But once back in the US a collections agency contacted me regarding a termination fee with AT&T, so I made yet another payment (around $40) with the scare that otherwise my credit score would be affected. In hindsight, I should have retrieved my receipts and pursued a reimbursement.

If I were in that position again, I would argue that by readily making the payment I sought to avoid hurting my credit score and instantly relied on the agency's representation that there was an outstanding amount. In other words, that I acted under a [mild] scenario of hardship.

If you decide to pursue a reimbursement, start by approaching the creditor/agency. If they deny your request, then go to Small Claims court.